# How to show that given inequality holds for some choices of a and n?

Tags: inequality, real-numbers

Show that there exists some $a\in \mathbb{R}$, $n\in \mathbb{N}\setminus\{0, 1, 2, 3\}$ such that $$\frac{(1+\sqrt[3]{|a|}\ \big)^{2n}}{n(n-1)(n-2)(2n-1)(2n-3)(2n-5)}\leq \frac{a^2}{90}.$$
I have tried by taking $a=8, 1000,  n=4, 5$ but not getting the result. Please help.

Comment: Doesn't seem true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First note that $a$ cannot be $0$.

Consider the even function$$f(a)=\frac{(1+|a|^{1/3})^{2n}}{a^2}$$For $a>0$,

$$\begin{align*}f'(a)=&\frac{2n(1+a^{1/3})^{2n-1}}{3a^{8/3}}-\frac{2(1+a^{1/3})^{2n}}{a^3}\\=&\frac{2(1+a^{1/3})^{2n-1}}{a^3}\left[\left(\frac n3-1\right)a^{1/3}-1\right]\end{align*}$$

The function attains global minimum at $a=\left(\frac n3-1\right)^{-3}$ with the minimum being$$f_\min(n)=\frac{n^{2n}}{3^6(n-3)^{2n-6}}$$

You can check that $\not\exists n\in\Bbb N_{\ge4}$ such that$$\begin{align*}f_\min(n)\le&\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)(2n-1)(2n-3)(2n-5)}{90}\\\iff0\le&\frac{(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)^{2n-6}(2n-1)(2n-3)(2n-5)}{n^{2n-1}}-\frac{10}{81}\end{align*}$$using a graphic calculator or program.